# Change result, using :split() [LUA]

Tags: lua

i just stuck in editing script.
The lines that make me trouble

```
  local name = Item(item):getName():split('+')
```

and

```
doItemSetAttribute(itemEx.uid, ITEM_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, it:getName()..((nLevel>0) and " +"..nLevel or ""))
```

Ok, this create exitem with new name in game, the result is for example:

> Armor +1

My target is to change it and get this:

> Armor (1%)

I edited this second line to this:

```
  doItemSetAttribute(itemEx.uid, ITEM_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, it:getName()..((nLevel>0) and  " ("..nLevel.."%)" or ""))
```

And when "upgrade" item in game, the script change item name to:

> Armor (1%)

But now by this line `local name = Item(item):getName():split('+')` The script dont see new item name properly to make next upgrade.

I try `local name = Item(item):getName():split('(','%))` etc. But i cant get it.
Should read item as Armor (x%).
I try get help here:
http://lua-users.org/wiki/SplitJoin

But i really cant get it :|
Anyone can throw little light?

Comment: If you can use `string.match` than you can do `local exName, exGrade = Item(item):getName():match("(%w+) %((%d+)%%%)"))`

Answer (score 0):

This should work, or something very similar.  I don't know your expected args for `doItemSetAttribute()` so I'm guessing there, but this looks right, with the information given.

```
function string .split( text, delimiter )
    local head, tail = text, ''  --  default returns what was given, with no added bonus
    local location = text :find( delimiter )
    if location then  --  if expected symbol exists, then do the split
        head = text :sub(  1,  location -1  )  --  before symbol
        tail = text :sub(  location +1,  -1  )  --  after symbol
    end
    return head, tail
end

local name, bonus = Item(item) :getName() :split('+')
if #bonus > 0 then bonus = '(' ..bonus ..'%)' end  --  add parenthesis if bonus exists
doItemSetAttribute( itemEx.uid,  ITEM_ATTRIBUTE_NAME,  name ..bonus )
```